# Pyspark - Reset cumulative sum column based on condition

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following dataframe:

```
+----+----------+-----+------+
|  id|      date|reset|cumsum|
+----+----------+-----+------+
|1001|2023-04-01|false|     0|
|1001|2023-04-02|false|     0|
|1001|2023-04-03|false|     1|
|1001|2023-04-04|false|     1|
|1001|2023-04-05| true|     4|
|1001|2023-04-06|false|     4|
|1001|2023-04-07|false|     4|
|1001|2023-04-08|false|    10|
|1001|2023-04-09| true|    10|
|1001|2023-04-10|false|    12|
|1001|2023-04-11|false|    13|
+----+----------+-----+------+
```

I am trying to create a new column, that resets `cumsum` when the `reset` column at a particular date is True.

Expected output:

```
+----+----------+-----+------+----------+
|  id|      date|reset|cumsum|new_cumsum|
+----+----------+-----+------+----------+
|1001|2023-04-01|false|     0|         0|
|1001|2023-04-02|false|     0|         0|
|1001|2023-04-03|false|     1|         1|
|1001|2023-04-04|false|     1|         1|
|1001|2023-04-05| true|     4|         3|
|1001|2023-04-06|false|     4|         3|
|1001|2023-04-07|false|     4|         3|
|1001|2023-04-08|false|    10|         6|
|1001|2023-04-09| true|    10|         0|
|1001|2023-04-10|false|    12|         2|
|1001|2023-04-11|false|    13|         3|
+----+----------+-----+------+----------+
```

Explanation of what is happening in the df above:

1. From 4/01 to 4/04, there is no reset flag, so the new value at each date should reflect the original.
2. At 4/05 we have our first reset, if the original value had remained 1, then the new value would be 0. But because it increased from 1 to 4 on that date, the new value is the difference (3)
3. From 4/05 to 4/07, the original values are unchanged at 4, so the new values should remain unchanged at 3.
4. At 4/08, the original increases from 4 to 10, so the new value should be the difference (6).
5. At 4/09 we have our second reset, because the value remained unchanged at 10 the new value at that date should be 0.
6. At 4/10 the original increases from 10 to 12 so the new values should be the difference (2).
7. At 4/11 the original increases from 12 to 13, so the new value should be the difference between the value at 4/11 and the value at the most recent reset date 4/09 (3).

Code for df:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (1001, "2023-04-01", False, 0, 0),
        (1001, "2023-04-02", False, 0, 0),
        (1001, "2023-04-03", False, 1, 1),
        (1001, "2023-04-04", False, 1, 1),
        (1001, "2023-04-05", True, 4, 3),
        (1001, "2023-04-06", False, 4, 3),
        (1001, "2023-04-07", False, 4, 3),
        (1001, "2023-04-08", False, 10, 6),
        (1001, "2023-04-09", True, 10, 0),
        (1001, "2023-04-10", False, 12, 2),
        (1001, "2023-04-11", False, 13, 3),
    ],
    ["id", "date", "reset", "cumsum", "new_cumsum"],
)
```

I hope this makes sense. A bit tricky to explain. Thank you in advance for any answers.

Comment: Between 04/07 and 04/08 `cumsum` goes up by 6 why didn't `new_cumsum` increase by 6?

Comment: I can see the logic but point number 4 doesn't make sense to me, shouldn't it be 9 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve it with a combination of window functions, the key observation is the prefix sum over the partition called "partition" that was constructed using the "reset" column, also I think you made an error in point 4, value should be 9 not 6:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (1001, "2023-04-01", False, 0, 0),
        (1001, "2023-04-02", False, 0, 0),
        (1001, "2023-04-03", False, 1, 1),
        (1001, "2023-04-04", False, 1, 1),
        (1001, "2023-04-05", True, 4, 3),
        (1001, "2023-04-06", False, 4, 3),
        (1001, "2023-04-07", False, 4, 3),
        (1001, "2023-04-08", False, 10, 6),
        (1001, "2023-04-09", True, 10, 0),
        (1001, "2023-04-10", False, 12, 2),
        (1001, "2023-04-11", False, 13, 3),
    ],
    ["id", "date", "reset", "cumsum", "new_cumsum"],
)

w = Window.orderBy("date")
w2 = Window.partitionBy("partition").orderBy("date")
df = df.withColumn("diff", col("cumsum") - lag("cumsum", default=0).over(w)) \
    .withColumn("partition", when(~col("reset"), 0).otherwise(1)) \
    .withColumn("partition", sum("partition").over(w)) \
    .withColumn("new_cumsum_2", sum(col("diff")).over(w2)).drop("diff", "partition")

df.show()
```

Result:

```
+----+----------+-----+------+----------+------------+
|  id|      date|reset|cumsum|new_cumsum|new_cumsum_2|
+----+----------+-----+------+----------+------------+
|1001|2023-04-01|false|     0|         0|           0|
|1001|2023-04-02|false|     0|         0|           0|
|1001|2023-04-03|false|     1|         1|           1|
|1001|2023-04-04|false|     1|         1|           1|
|1001|2023-04-05| true|     4|         3|           3|
|1001|2023-04-06|false|     4|         3|           3|
|1001|2023-04-07|false|     4|         3|           3|
|1001|2023-04-08|false|    10|         6|           9|
|1001|2023-04-09| true|    10|         0|           0|
|1001|2023-04-10|false|    12|         2|           2|
|1001|2023-04-11|false|    13|         3|           3|
+----+----------+-----+------+----------+------------+
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you very much. And yes I was incorrect at point 4, value should be 9 not 6.