# Pyspark - Selectively reset cumulative sum column

Tags: python, pyspark

I have the following dataframe in which I am trying to convert the `cumsum` column to look like the `new_cumsum` column. `id_B_entry_date` is the `date` the corresponding `id_B` is introduced to this population.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (1001, 2001, "2023-04-01", "2023-04-01", False, 0, 0),
        (1001, 2001, "2023-04-02", "2023-04-01", False, 0, 0),
        (1001, 2001, "2023-04-03", "2023-04-01", False, 1, 1),
        (1001, 2001, "2023-04-04", "2023-04-01", False, 1, 1),
        (1001, 2002, "2023-04-05", "2023-04-05", True, 4, 3),
        (1001, 2001, "2023-04-05", "2023-04-01", False, 4, 4),
        (1001, 2001, "2023-04-06", "2023-04-01", False, 4, 4),
        (1001, 2002, "2023-04-06", "2023-04-05", False, 4, 3),
        (1001, 2001, "2023-04-07", "2023-04-01", False, 4, 4),
        (1001, 2002, "2023-04-07", "2023-04-05", False, 4, 3),
        (1001, 2001, "2023-04-08", "2023-04-01", False, 10, 10),
        (1001, 2002, "2023-04-08", "2023-04-05", False, 10, 9),
        (1001, 2003, "2023-04-09", "2023-04-09", True, 10, 0),
        (1001, 2001, "2023-04-09", "2023-04-01", False, 10, 10),
        (1001, 2002, "2023-04-09", "2023-04-05", False, 10, 9),
        (1001, 2001, "2023-04-10", "2023-04-01", False, 12, 12),
        (1001, 2002, "2023-04-10", "2023-04-05", False, 12, 11), 
        (1001, 2003, "2023-04-10", "2023-04-09", False, 12, 2),
        (1001, 2001, "2023-04-11", "2023-04-01", False, 13, 13),
        (1001, 2002, "2023-04-11", "2023-04-05", False, 13, 12),
        (1001, 2003, "2023-04-11", "2023-04-09", False, 13, 3),
    ],
    ["id_A", "id_B", "date", "id_B_entry_date", "reset", "cumsum", "new_cumsum"],
)
df.show()
+----+----+----------+---------------+-----+------+----------+
|id_A|id_B|      date|id_B_entry_date|reset|cumsum|new_cumsum|
+----+----+----------+---------------+-----+------+----------+
|1001|2001|2023-04-01|     2023-04-01|false|     0|         0|
|1001|2001|2023-04-02|     2023-04-01|false|     0|         0|
|1001|2001|2023-04-03|     2023-04-01|false|     1|         1|
|1001|2001|2023-04-04|     2023-04-01|false|     1|         1|
|1001|2002|2023-04-05|     2023-04-05| true|     4|         3|
|1001|2001|2023-04-05|     2023-04-01|false|     4|         4|
|1001|2001|2023-04-06|     2023-04-01|false|     4|         4|
|1001|2002|2023-04-06|     2023-04-05|false|     4|         3|
|1001|2001|2023-04-07|     2023-04-01|false|     4|         4|
|1001|2002|2023-04-07|     2023-04-05|false|     4|         3|
|1001|2001|2023-04-08|     2023-04-01|false|    10|        10|
|1001|2002|2023-04-08|     2023-04-05|false|    10|         9|
|1001|2003|2023-04-09|     2023-04-09| true|    10|         0|
|1001|2001|2023-04-09|     2023-04-01|false|    10|        10|
|1001|2002|2023-04-09|     2023-04-05|false|    10|         9|
|1001|2001|2023-04-10|     2023-04-01|false|    12|        12|
|1001|2002|2023-04-10|     2023-04-05|false|    12|        11|
|1001|2003|2023-04-10|     2023-04-09|false|    12|         2|
|1001|2001|2023-04-11|     2023-04-01|false|    13|        13|
|1001|2002|2023-04-11|     2023-04-05|false|    13|        12|
|1001|2003|2023-04-11|     2023-04-09|false|    13|         3|
+----+----+----------+---------------+-----+------+----------+
```

The logic here is to reset `cumsum` whenever a new `id_B` is introduced, but keep the `cumsum` of rows with pre-existing id_Bs.

For example, on 2023-04-05, `id_B` 2002 is introduced so I want to reset the `cumsum` for it at that date. It just so happens that the `cumsum` increased from 1 to 4 on that date so the `new_cumsum` should be 3. However, the `cumsum` for `id_B` 2001 on that date should not reset.

On 2023-04-09, `id_B` 2003 is introduced. Since the `cumsum` remained at 10 for that date, the reset should calculate the respective `new_cumsum` as 0. `id_B` 2001 and 2002 should not have a reset on this date.

I've tried several methods, with the following being the closest to what I need but it's just not quite there.

```
w1 = Window.partitionBy("id_A").orderBy("date")
w2 = Window.partitionBy("id_A", "id_B_entry_date").orderBy("date")
w3 = Window.partitionBy("partition2", "id_A", "id_B_entry_date").orderBy("date")

df2 = (
    df
    .withColumn("diff", F.col("cumsum") - F.lag("cumsum", default=0).over(w2))
    .withColumn("partition", F.when(F.col("reset"), 1).otherwise(0))
    .withColumn("partition2", F.sum("partition").over(w1))
    .withColumn("new_cumsum_attempt", F.sum(F.col("diff")).over(w3))
    .drop("diff", "partition", "partition2")
)

df2.orderBy('date').show()
+----+----+----------+---------------+-----+------+----------+------------------+
|id_A|id_B|      date|id_B_entry_date|reset|cumsum|new_cumsum|new_cumsum_attempt|
+----+----+----------+---------------+-----+------+----------+------------------+
|1001|2001|2023-04-01|     2023-04-01|false|     0|         0|                 0|
|1001|2001|2023-04-02|     2023-04-01|false|     0|         0|                 0|
|1001|2001|2023-04-03|     2023-04-01|false|     1|         1|                 1|
|1001|2001|2023-04-04|     2023-04-01|false|     1|         1|                 1|
|1001|2001|2023-04-05|     2023-04-01|false|     4|         4|                 3|
|1001|2002|2023-04-05|     2023-04-05| true|     4|         3|                 4|
|1001|2001|2023-04-06|     2023-04-01|false|     4|         4|                 3|
|1001|2002|2023-04-06|     2023-04-05|false|     4|         3|                 4|
|1001|2001|2023-04-07|     2023-04-01|false|     4|         4|                 3|
|1001|2002|2023-04-07|     2023-04-05|false|     4|         3|                 4|
|1001|2001|2023-04-08|     2023-04-01|false|    10|        10|                 9|
|1001|2002|2023-04-08|     2023-04-05|false|    10|         9|                10|
|1001|2001|2023-04-09|     2023-04-01|false|    10|        10|                 0|
|1001|2002|2023-04-09|     2023-04-05|false|    10|         9|                 0|
|1001|2003|2023-04-09|     2023-04-09| true|    10|         0|                10|
|1001|2001|2023-04-10|     2023-04-01|false|    12|        12|                 2|
|1001|2002|2023-04-10|     2023-04-05|false|    12|        11|                 2|
|1001|2003|2023-04-10|     2023-04-09|false|    12|         2|                12|
|1001|2001|2023-04-11|     2023-04-01|false|    13|        13|                 3|
|1001|2002|2023-04-11|     2023-04-05|false|    13|        12|                 3|
|1001|2003|2023-04-11|     2023-04-09|false|    13|         3|                13|
+----+----+----------+---------------+-----+------+----------+------------------+
```

I've asked a [similar question in the past](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76076409/pyspark-reset-cumulative-sum-column-based-on-condition), but the caveat here is keeping the cumulative sum in some cases rather than always resetting.

Thank you in advance for any responses.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood but you can create a column `reset_cumsum` to selectively reset the cumulative sum with the `lag` method.

Comment: why is the eighth row's `new_cumsum` = 3? `id_b` in that row isn't new

Comment: @samkart, the reset happens for `id_B` 2002 in row 6 (when it's introduced). `new_cumsum` is 3 for that `id_B` because the `cumsum` increased from 1 to 4 on that day (2023-04-05). In row 8, the `cumsum` hasn't increased yet, so the `new_cumsum` should remain at 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to figure it out with a combination of window functions and creating a `lag2` column to account for rows with duplicate dates (since `cumsum` is always the same on any particular date).

```
w0 = Window.partitionBy("id_A", "id_B").orderBy("date", "id_B_entry_date")
w1 = Window.partitionBy("id_A").orderBy("date")
w2 = Window.partitionBy("id_A").orderBy("id_B_entry_date")
w3 = Window.partitionBy("partition", "id_A", "id_B").orderBy("date")

df2 = (
    df
    .withColumn("lag", F.lag("cumsum", default=0).over(w0))
    .withColumn(
        "lag2", 
        F.when(F.col("lag")==0, F.max("lag", default=0).over(w1))
        .otherwise(F.col("lag"))
    )
    .withColumn("partition", F.rank().over(w2))
    .withColumn("diff", F.col("cumsum") - F.col("lag2"))
    .withColumn("new_cumsum_attempt", F.sum(F.col("diff")).over(w3))
    .withColumn("check", F.col("new_cumsum")==F.col("new_cumsum_attempt"))
)

df2.orderBy('date').show(21)
+----+----+----------+---------------+-----+------+----------+---+----+---------+----+------------------+-----+
|id_A|id_B|      date|id_B_entry_date|reset|cumsum|new_cumsum|lag|lag2|partition|diff|new_cumsum_attempt|check|
+----+----+----------+---------------+-----+------+----------+---+----+---------+----+------------------+-----+
|1001|2001|2023-04-01|     2023-04-01|false|     0|         0|  0|   0|        1|   0|                 0| true|
|1001|2001|2023-04-02|     2023-04-01|false|     0|         0|  0|   0|        1|   0|                 0| true|
|1001|2001|2023-04-03|     2023-04-01|false|     1|         1|  0|   0|        1|   1|                 1| true|
|1001|2001|2023-04-04|     2023-04-01|false|     1|         1|  1|   1|        1|   0|                 1| true|
|1001|2001|2023-04-05|     2023-04-01|false|     4|         4|  1|   1|        1|   3|                 4| true|
|1001|2002|2023-04-05|     2023-04-05| true|     4|         3|  0|   1|       12|   3|                 3| true|
|1001|2001|2023-04-06|     2023-04-01|false|     4|         4|  4|   4|        1|   0|                 4| true|
|1001|2002|2023-04-06|     2023-04-05|false|     4|         3|  4|   4|       12|   0|                 3| true|
|1001|2001|2023-04-07|     2023-04-01|false|     4|         4|  4|   4|        1|   0|                 4| true|
|1001|2002|2023-04-07|     2023-04-05|false|     4|         3|  4|   4|       12|   0|                 3| true|
|1001|2001|2023-04-08|     2023-04-01|false|    10|        10|  4|   4|        1|   6|                10| true|
|1001|2002|2023-04-08|     2023-04-05|false|    10|         9|  4|   4|       12|   6|                 9| true|
|1001|2001|2023-04-09|     2023-04-01|false|    10|        10| 10|  10|        1|   0|                10| true|
|1001|2002|2023-04-09|     2023-04-05|false|    10|         9| 10|  10|       12|   0|                 9| true|
|1001|2003|2023-04-09|     2023-04-09| true|    10|         0|  0|  10|       19|   0|                 0| true|
|1001|2001|2023-04-10|     2023-04-01|false|    12|        12| 10|  10|        1|   2|                12| true|
|1001|2002|2023-04-10|     2023-04-05|false|    12|        11| 10|  10|       12|   2|                11| true|
|1001|2003|2023-04-10|     2023-04-09|false|    12|         2| 10|  10|       19|   2|                 2| true|
|1001|2001|2023-04-11|     2023-04-01|false|    13|        13| 12|  12|        1|   1|                13| true|
|1001|2002|2023-04-11|     2023-04-05|false|    13|        12| 12|  12|       12|   1|                12| true|
|1001|2003|2023-04-11|     2023-04-09|false|    13|         3| 12|  12|       19|   1|                 3| true|
+----+----+----------+---------------+-----+------+----------+---+----+---------+----+------------------+-----+
```